# Python atomic access (related to threads)

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

When you start using threads, you have to understand very well some things, mostly about synchronization of shared data. You have to use locks, rlocks, semaphores and so on. Is it write even with very simple shared data?

For example, I have two threads that share a global resource, a simple boolean variable.

```
import threading
import random
import time

active = True

class T1(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while active:
            print("Hello")      # do some work
            time.sleep(0.1)

class T2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global active
        while random.random() > 0.05:
            time.sleep(1)
        active = False

t1, t2 = T1(), T2()
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

It seems it works, but does python guarantees it works? If yes, exactly for what reason it works?

I have three answers.

1. It works because the access of a boolean variable is always atomic (it can't be interrupted by another thread). In this case, what Python guarantees as atomic operation? Is the access of an integer, a list, a dictionary atomic?
2. Python doesn't guarantee this code works every time. The solution is to use a lock to access active variable in both thread.
3. It works because only one thread writes the variable. The other thread only reads it.

Here it is another code:

```
import threading
import random
import time

numbers = [3]

class T1(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while sum(numbers) % 3 == 0:
            print("Hello")      # do some work
            time.sleep(0.1)

class T2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global active
        while random.random() > 0.2:
            numbers.extend([1, 2])
            time.sleep(1)
        numbers.append(4)

t1, t2 = T1(), T2()
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Now could the **single and "complex"** instruction *numbers.extend([1, 2])* be interrupted by T1 thread? If this is the case, just after 1 is added but before 2 is added, T1 could stop unintentionally before T2.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: It Always Works (In CPython at least)

It works because of the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

This guarantees no two threads are executing Python code at the same time, so there can never be simultaneous reads/writes.

If you have a question about a particular non-CPython implementation, that probably deservies its own question.

I think other Python implementations (besides CPython) do try to preserve some behavior that programmers using CPython have come to rely on, but I'm not sure how/to what extent each project does so.

Comment: Note that lines from the two threads might be interleaved arbitrarily, but your code doesn't really depend on any series of actions being atomic (which would require more care on your part). Your code only relies on single lines being executed atomically, which should always be reliable in CPython

Comment: What do you mean with "code at the same time" and "on a single variable"? 
In Python a *single* instruction could make many things on variables and complex objects. Does Python guarantees all single instructions (such as copy between two objects or loops or function calls...) can't be interrupted by another thread? How could I understand when a thread can interrupt another?

Comment: *I think, but don't know* that a thread can interrupt another thread between any two instructions. The expression `i = 2 + 3 * 10 + 17` has many separate instructions, however the full right side is evaluated, and at the end the assignment `i = 49` will occur. If the value of `i` was previously `10`, another thread who is repeatedly checking the value of `i` will only ever see `i == 10` or `i == 49`. `i` is never in between during the computation of `2 + 3 * 10 + 17`